# Custom UI elements of prototype cell are not accessible xcode 6 beta

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode6

I am using a **UITableView** with prototype cells. I am adding custom elements (**UILabel**, **UIProgressView**) to these **prototype cells**. I then want to initialize these elements using their tags in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**.

Looks like boilerplate design... but it doesn't work.
I am not able to access the **UILabel** and the **UIProgressView** components with **viewWithTag**, it looks like there is nothing in the **contentView** inside the cell prototype.

The funny thing is, it works in **XCode 5**, *but not* in **XCode 6 beta** 3 to 5.
Also, when I'm opening my project with XCode 6, the design that was initially setup with XCode 5 is all messed up. I can repair it manually, but then some objects are not visible anymore as if they were laying outside of the screen.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellFileDown"];

    NSLog(@"cell.contentView subViews: %@", [cell.contentView subviews]);

    UILabel *nameLabel = ((UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:10]);
    nameLabel.text = @"hello test";

    NSLog(@"nameLabel: %@", nameLabel);

    return cell;
}
```

*console log output :*

```
cell.contentView subViews: ()
nameLabel: (null)

...(5 times)
```

***Picture here:***
[My screen when I launch IOs Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqqcX.png)

*You can see here that **the prototype cell's UILabel doesn't change (I have already checked the tags)** and UIProgressView are outside the screen*

Is this a known bug from XCode 6, or is it just me who is unable to use the new IB ?

I can add all the features manually using **contentView addSubview** but obviously I want to use the StoryBoard.

**EDIT: Solution to that issue(*[@codeIgnitor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829487/codeignitor)*)**

*replace:*

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellFileDown"];
```

*with:*

```
cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellFileDown" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe the xcode 6 new storyboard feature  `W:any H:any` so if you are trying to open this in xcode 5, your xcode 5 doesnt know the new features introduced so sometimes your entire view gets messed up. I have experienced this! so always take a back up with such experiments but

Below code works fine in Xcode beta 4

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
        {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
     UILabel *headLinesLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:101];
            headLinesLabel.text = newsData.headlineTitle;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Actually I had the `W:Any H:Any` setting properly configured, however I realized I was missing the `forIndexPath:indexPath` parameter in the call to `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`.

It is still unclear why you now need to use this extra parameter with XCode 6. It used to work perfectly without it in XCode 5.

Comment: Difference is that , `- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier;  // Used by the delegate to acquire an already allocated cell but
- (id)dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  // newer dequeue method guarantees a cell is returned and resized properly, assuming identifier is registered`